# Conditional include with empty value in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I hope that I understood JSF correct and this all makes sense. I try to do some kind of simple templating within a page by using (conditional) includes.
The panel is updated by a selection.

```
<p:outputPanel id="panel">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty someBean.selectedObject}">
    <ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/#{someBean.selectedObject.pageName}.xhtml" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</p:outputPanel>
```

If I am right the `ui:include` got processed in some kind of view preparation phase and the `rendered` attribute just before the page gets rendered. As a result I get a FileNotFoundException because it tries to load WEB-INF/pages/.xhtml. This makes quite some sense to me, but how to solve this problem without a messy hackaround like creating an empty page as a prefix for the filename (page.xhtml) and prefix every page that should be actually rendered with this string (pageSamplePage.xhtml)?

Comment: may Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405708/conditionally-including-a-facelet-file-via-uiinclude/26405938#26405938

Comment: Don't think that because the page to be included in the linked question exists. The non-existence is my core problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to conditionally build the `<ui:include>` instead of conditionally render it. Use `<c:if>` instead of `rendered`.

```
<p:outputPanel id="panel">
  <c:if test="#{not empty someBean.selectedObject}">
    <ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/#{someBean.selectedObject.pageName}.xhtml" />
  </c:if>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Otherwise, the `<ui:include>` still ends up in the component tree.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, even when you intend to conditionally render parts of the view, you'd better use `<ui:fragment>` instead of `<h:panelGroup>` as it has less overhead.

Comment: I read the linked post and it makes sense ;) but it does not work :( Now it seems to fall through the if statement. Even a hard-coded false jumps into the wrapped statement. I updated the question with the sample snipplet. Is there any configuration I may check for JSF. I just have one year experience with jsf and I am always fighting with this corner cases. ;)

Comment: What the ...? you are right I can see the `c:if` tags in my html. But I declared `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"` in the `ui:composition` tag at the beginning of the 'file' (this page is also just part of the main template in case it matters.)

Comment: Thanks. That was the reason. I filtered the taglib containing jsp as nonsense when my IDE suggested it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Prevent usage of `<c:if>`, as it can break some of the standard JSF components.
We observed that its usage caused duplication of a child within UI:Panel as a side-effect, and it took a while to identify this as the root-cause.